# How do I rotate hexagon points I've generated or generate it so that the first point is center-top?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

So I have this code:

```
var points = 6;
var width = w;
var height = h;
var angle = ((2 * Math.PI) / points);
var hexagon = [];

for (i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    hexagon.push({
        x: width * Math.cos(angle * i), 
        y: height * Math.sin(angle * i)
    })
}
```

Which will produce 6 points/locations and if I draw a line between them I get a hexagon, but I want to rotate the points or generate the points differently so that the first point is always  center-top, like so:

[image: hexagons]
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Since you're off by 30 degrees I'd guess adding 30 to angle would do it.

Comment: Generalizing this problem...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

So you could have done something like `x' = x*Math.cos(angle*i) - y*Math.sin(angle*i)`. But both other solutions I've seen seem fine honestly if this is a one-off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just swap `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: Had been hunting. This was the simplest solution I'd come across.