# How can I draw a hexagon in Java Scene Builder 2.0?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx, shapes

I want to create a custom shape in Java Scene Builder - hexagon. I tried using the "Polygon" option but the only thing I get, is a triangle. 
Does anyone know how can I edit this? I read somewhere that I should set the shape to "resizeable" but the option in Java Scene Builder is inactive...

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
 <Polygon fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="121.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE">
 <points>

<Double fx:value="-50.0" />
<Double fx:value="30.0" />

<Double fx:value="0.0" />
<Double fx:value="60.0" />

<Double fx:value="50.0" />
<Double fx:value="30.0" />

<Double fx:value="50.0" />
<Double fx:value="-30.0" />

<Double fx:value="0.0" />
<Double fx:value="-60.0" />

<Double fx:value="-50.0" />
<Double fx:value="-30.0" />



 </points>
</Polygon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the scene builder as I've never used it, but if you can't get that working you could do it manually. According to [the documentation on polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) you create a polygon with `Polygon(double... points)`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982502/how-do-i-rotate-hexagon-points-ive-generated-or-generate-it-so-that-the-first-p) has a way to get the right points.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this class

```
  class Hexagon {
    double [] points;
    double center;
    public Hexagon(double side){
      center = getH(side);
      points = new double[12];
      //     X                          Y
      points[0] = 0.0;           points[1] = 0.0;
      points[2] = side;          points[3] = 0.0;
      points[4] = side+(side/2); points[5] = center;
      points[6] = side;          points[7] = center * 2;
      points[8] = 0.0;           points[9] = center * 2;
      points[10] = -side/2;      points[11] = center;

    }

    private double getH(double side) {
      return ((sqrt(3)/2)*side);
    }
    public double [] getPoints(){
      return points;
    }
  }
```

And you can use it for  create a polygon just like this:

```
Polygon hexagon = new Polygon(new Hexagon(100d).getPoints());
```